# Why does Enum.GetName() ask for a Type when this information is passed with the object parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, parameters, enums

Consider the .NET function signature:

```
Enum.GetName(Type type, object o);
```

Is seems entirely unnecessary to ask for the `Type` when this information is passed with `object o`

The following code illustrates this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public enum Color
    {
        Black, White, Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Purple, Pink,
        DarkRed, DarkGreen, DarkBlue,
        NeonGreen, NeonBlue
    }
    class Program
    {
        private static Random rand = new Random();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Color color = getRandomColor();
            PrintType(color);
            Console.WriteLine("typeof = " + typeof(Color));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void PrintType(object o) 
        {
            Type type = o.GetType();
            Console.WriteLine("type = " + type);
        }

        private static Color getRandomColor()
        {
            var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Color));
            Color randomColor = (Color)values.GetValue(rand.Next(values.Length));
            return randomColor;
        }
    }
}
```

The output is

```
type = ConsoleApplication1.Color
typeof = ConsoleApplication1.Color
```

Which means that the `Enum.GetName()` method signature could look like this instead:

```
Enum.GetName(object o);
```

Comment: FYI, this is a question about the .NET Framework, not about the C# programming language.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`o` does not need to be of type `Color`. Example:

```
Enum.GetName(typeof(Color), 3) // == Orange
```

Comment: Good answer, but I can't upvote unless I have 15 rep :(

Comment: Better question, then: why didn't they add a simple `Enum.GetName(Enum enumval)` to the class? It's a silly thing I always end up putting in my tool class.

Comment: @Nyerguds My guess: Because that would require generics which where introduced later than enums.

Comment: @SebastianNegraszus Actually, I originally thought so too, but you don't. You just return `Enum.GetName(enumval.GetType(), enumval)`. The fact the function argument only accepts the type `Enum` takes care of the type safety.

Comment: It'll obviously fail if you give it `null`, but that's completely deserved in my opinion, and you can always build in an advance check for that anyway ;)